# In Flutter, how can we avoid writing boilerplate codes with very long object/attribute names?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example:

`Text(objectNameVeryLong.attributeNameVeryLong.isEmpty ? "Sorry It's Empty" : objectNameVeryLong.attributeNameVeryLong)` is really a piece of spaghetti.

However dart language does not support "inline expression" syntax like:

`Text({var a = studentId.toString(); a = a.isNotEmpty ? a : "empty";}) //the last line becomes the expression return value`

The {code} here eventually becomes a variable.

The solutions I've came up with are:

1. Call an anonymous function/closure inline, like

`Text((){var a = studentId.toString(); a = a.isNotEmpty ? a : "empty"; return a;}())`

2. Introduce a variable in the class (jump wire), however it's not a good practice in flutter in my opinion since variable assigning happens in argument-passing most of the time.

Are there any other solutions regarding this problem? or are there any dart language experimental proposals towards this problem?

Comment: can't you just name your objects and attributes more concisely?

Comment: @ColeHenrich Sometimes the API just goes bloated, or backend devs decided to name it that way. Our VO class have no other choice but to keep the naming consistent...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, largest names it's not bad, because is more explicit and help to understand the code (but it's ugly). My solutions are:

1. Create getters:

```
T get getterWithReasonableNameLong => this.attributeNameVeryLong.isEmpty ? "Sorry It's Empty" : this.attributeNameVeryLong;

// ...

Text(objectNameVeryLong.getterWithReasonableNameLong)
```

2. Create helper functions:

```
T buildMessage(message) => message.isEmpty ? "Sorry It's Empty" : maessage;

// ...
Text(buildMessage(objectNameVeryLong.attributeNameVeryLong))
```